# How to create and save data on the go in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have 2 domain classes

Expenditure

```
class Expenditure {
   Date date
   Supplier supplier
   String particular
   BigDecimal amount
}
```

Supplier

```
class Supplier {
   String name
   String address

   static hasMany = [expenditures: Expenditure]
}
```

What happening is that when I create a new expenditure, I will enter the supplier from the list of suppliers in the Supplier class. When the supplier is not exist, I will have to create it first and then select it when creating the expenditure.

What I want is that, when I enter the supplier it will be looked up, and when not found, it will be created on the go (when saving the expenditure instance) without me having to create it first in the Supplier table and then come back to Expenditure to complete the form.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are the `findOrCreate...` helpers

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is that, when I enter the supplier it will be looked up,
>   and when not found, it will be created on the go

One option you have is to do something like one of these...

```
Supplier.findOrCreateByName('some name goes here')
Supplier.findOrCreateByNameAndAddress('some name goes here', 'some address goes here')
```

There are also `findOrSaveBy...` counterparts but those only work if you are supplying enough search criteria to create a fully save-able instance.

I hope that helps.